Angular 18, primeng 17.18.1: toolbar with custom icons
I'm using the following code for a toolbar with PNG external icons.
It works.
The icon is placed on a background png image.
The color I used is the same as the background.
This way the button frame is not displayed.
Is this the right way ?


:host {

    .ui-toolbar-container {
      background-image: url('../../../../public/icons/Header.png');
      height: 54px;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
    }
  
  }

.ui-button {
  color:#095166;
  margin-top: -10px;

}
  
<div class="ui-toolbar-container">
    <button pButton type="button" outlined="true" class="ui-button" >
        <img alt="button icon" src="icons/icon-play.png" >
    </button>
</div>



